# Meaning of the key packagist in composer

Tags: php, composer-php

In the file composer.json of many projects I find:

```
"packagist" : false
```

What would interest me is what this key does and why it is used?
In the Composer documentation, I read that it has something to do with the repository packagist.org, but I did not quite understand it (I'm new to composer).
Above all, the meaning does not clear to me. So far I thought that everything is included by default by GitHub?

Answer (score 2):

By default Composer always fetches packages form `packagist.org`. You can add your own repositories with packages, but these will be addition to packages from `packagist.org`. By using `"packagist" : false` you can ignore packages from `packagist.org` and use only custom repositories - this may  be useful when you want to use local source of packages to get more control what Composer is installing:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "packagist.org": false
    },
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://packages.example.org/"
    }
],
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your explanation. If I understood correctly, it would only work for frameworks that have the same name and vendor, isn't it? So if I have e.g. zendframework/zend-mvc in my custom repository, then I can use the packagist entry to block the download of the same framework from packagist.org? What happens if my framework is called myvendor/zend-mvc instead? Does that also work then?

Comment: Custom repositories may add new or replace existing packages, so it will work for both cases. You don't need to use `"packagist" : false` for that, just add your custom repository to `repositories` section. `"packagist" : false` makes sense only if you want use **only** custom repositories (and ignore these thousands of packages from `packagist.org`). If you don't have any reason to ignore packages from `packagist.org`, then don't bother this option - it's quite niche and I doubt you actually need it.